# Java Scheduled Job, timeout during long sql transaction

Tags: java, sql, oracle, scheduler, connection-timeout

**Overview**
I have an @Scheduled job (using cron), called service method which provides some transactions to oracle database.

**Problem**
The problem is, that in some cases (big data processing) those transactions may last a long time (~17 minutes).
In the case of that duration, I get an exception's:

> SQLTimeoutException: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current
>   operation
>
> QueryTimeoutException: PreparedStatementCallback;

That problem appears on spring-boot and Tomcat server as well.

**Question**

How I may avoid that behavior in my case, and which way would be the best ?
As I know, it is possible to set up query timeout, but according to:
[this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int)) -  as default it is not some limitation for query timeout.

Comment: the description of the error states that the query was cancelled, so from what I understood here it could be the driver, have you tried  setQueryTimeout(int seconds)?

Comment: @nsawaya setQueryTimeout(int seconds) 
the documentation of this method via link i posted describes, that:
By default there is no limit on the amount of time allowed for a running statement to complete

Comment: Can you then try the getQueryTimeout() method to see if there is something set someplace?

Comment: @nsawaya good point, I’ll try